# not getting the res.send message with axios (nodeJs express sequelize react)

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, sequelize.js

I'm creating a new record and I want to send a message to the user if the record already exists

I programmed an endpoint as

```
let newVideo = { title, origin, author, url, videoCategoryId, excerpt };
let video = await Video.findOne({ where: { url: newVideo.url } });
if (!video) {
    newVideo.uploadDate = uploadDate;
    video = await Video.create({ ...newVideo });
    if (video) return res.status(200).send('Video successfully created');
    else return res.status(501).send('Video not created');
} else {
    res.status(501);
    return res.send('video already exists'); // THIS MESSAGE GETS LOST, I CAN'T GET IT
}
```

in the font-end, I used Axios as:

```
export function addVideo(videoObj) {
    let apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/videos/add';

    const request = axios.post(apiUrl, videoObj);

    return (dispatch) => {
        function onSuccess(success) {
            dispatch(setVideosDirty());
            dispatch(setVideoCategoriesDirty());
            return success;
        }
        function onError(error) {
            dispatch(setVideosFailure(error));
            return error;
        }
        request.then((success) => onSuccess(success), (error) => onError(error));
    };
}
```

If I try to create a video with a URL that already exists, then I only get the message

> Error: Request failed with status code 501

but I can't get the message video already exists, which I sent

```
res.send('video already exists');
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I got it

```
export function addVideo(videoObj) {
    let apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/videos/add';

    const request = axios.post(apiUrl, videoObj);

    return (dispatch) => {
        function onSuccess(success) {
            dispatch(setVideosDirty());
            dispatch(setVideoCategoriesDirty());
            return success;
        }
        function onError(error) {
            dispatch(setVideosFailure(error.request.response));
            return error;
        }
        request.then((success) => onSuccess(success), (error) => onError(error));
    };
}
```

error.request.response is the answer